# Magento Remove/Hide Shipiing and Handling and Discount in cart page

Tags: shipping, grand-total, magento-1.9.3.4

In Magento 1.9.3.4, How to Remove/Hide Shipiing and Handling and Discount in cart page.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To remove Shipping and Handling fee please check your Shipping method settings you will have setup **Handling Fee** remove that it will not show on checkout. I have attached screenshot as well. [image: handling fee]